# how to know how many hardlink count an inode has and where are they located

Tags: hard-link, inode

I need to know how many hard-links pointing to a certain inode.
And where are those hard-links located in?

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Hard-Links.html

Comment: i tried ln -samefile /usr/bin/eclipse but it returned ln: invalid option -- 'a'.. any idea why?

Comment: silly me its a find command lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hard link count can be established with tools like `stat(1)` or even `ls(1)`.

To find all hard links use `find [...] -samefile [PATH]`.